# Port Forwarding Ubuntu to Debian server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, port-forwarding

I have xxx Ubuntu 18.4 Desktop which is connected to the Internet and have a Debian Server which is not connected to the Internet directly but hosting a cacti server on the same network with different private IP block and reachable vice-versa.

I want xxx server to have access to the cacti server like browsing public IP of xxx PC from windows client with 8000 ports, requests would be forwarded to yyy server and responding back as well.

Note that I have full administrative access to xxx server but yyy server is reachable but don't have administrative access.

Inside the office network, I can reach yyy server from xxx server without any issue.
But from outside I can reach xxx server - can do ssh but with the terminal, I can't see the cacti graph.

Tried googling it and it ends up with multiple failed attempts - tried with IP Tables, tired to ssh but unable to find a solution.

How to achieve this basic requirement? Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user535733, Many Thanks for the reply. Could you please give advice on SSH Tunnel? I have read the documentation and looks like puzzled to me.